# T-SQL multiple subqueries with JOIN and MAX(date)

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have this query with 2 `LEFT JOINS` each with a sub-query.

The sub-queries should select the row with the latest date `PointsChangeDate__c` for a specific campaign e.g: `PointsTypeCode__c = '1'`.

Problem is that it is choosing what appears to be just random dates.

If I run just one `JOIN` / `sub-query`, then the result is correct, but when I add the 2nd `JOIN` / `sub-query`, then the results are incorrect and it seems to be pulling random dates.

I suspect my issue is with the type of JOIN I am using, but I cannot see why, because if I `LEFT JOIN`, then I am including all results (`a._ContactKey`) pulled from the first query and carrying that all the way through.

```
SELECT 
    a._ContactKey ContactId,
    a.Full_Name_1__c Full_Name,
    a.MC_Phone__c Mobile,
    a.POSCustomerNumber__c POS_Customer_Number,
    a.POSCustomerStatus__c POSCustomerStatus,
    'IL' Locale,
    a.Mobile_1__c Mobile_for_text,
    g.TotalPoints__c TotalPoints_SourceMethod_1,
    g.ValidUntil__c ValidUntil_SourceMethod_1,
    g.date_1 PointsChangeDate__c_1,
    h.TotalPoints__c TotalPoints_SourceMethod_2,
    h.ValidUntil__c ValidUntil_SourceMethod_2,
    h.date_2 PointsChangeDate__c_2

FROM
    Contact_Salesforce AS a
       LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT 
        Contact__c,
            TotalPoints__c,
            ValidUntil__c,
           MAX(PointsChangeDate__c) date_1
    FROM
        Member_points__c_Salesforce 
    WHERE
        PointsTypeCode__c = '1' 

    GROUP BY Contact__c , TotalPoints__c , ValidUntil__c, PointsChangeDate__c) AS g ON a._ContactKey = g.Contact__c 

     LEFT JOIN
        (SELECT Contact__c,
            TotalPoints__c,
            ValidUntil__c,
           MAX(PointsChangeDate__c) date_2
    FROM
        Member_points__c_Salesforce 
    WHERE
        PointsTypeCode__c = '2' 
    GROUP BY Contact__c , TotalPoints__c , ValidUntil__c, PointsChangeDate__c) AS h ON h.Contact__c = g.Contact__c


        LEFT JOIN
    SMS_Unsubscribe AS c ON REPLACE(CONCAT('972',
                RIGHT(RTRIM(LTRIM(a.Mobile_1__c)), 9)),
        '-',
        '') = c.Mobile
        LEFT JOIN
    Member_Segments__c_Salesforce AS b ON b.Contact__c = a._ContactKey
 WHERE
   a.Mobile_1__c IS NOT NULL
        AND c.Mobile IS NULL
        AND a.POSCustomerStatus__c = '0'
        AND b.IsActive__c = 'true'
GROUP BY a._ContactKey , a.Full_Name_1__c , a.MC_Phone__c , a.POSCustomerNumber__c , a.POSCustomerStatus__c , Locale , a.Mobile_1__c , a.Mobile_1__c , b.SegmentTypeID__c, b.SegmentTypeDescription__c , b.ToDate__c  , g.TotalPoints__c , g.ValidUntil__c, g.date_1
,h.TotalPoints__c , h.ValidUntil__c, h.date_2
```

[image]

Comment: Can you maybe provide us with sample data and expected results?

Comment: I added some data and also the results I am getting.

Comment: More than anything, we need sample INPUT.  And preferably in a way that is easily consumed (table creation and insert statements).  As it stands, I'm looking at your query and not seeing anything indeterministic about it.  Is it possible that the base data is just changing quickly between runs?

Comment: I tend to write these using common table expressions, it makes them easier to test the results of each subquery

Comment: I have run the queries seperatley and get the correct results. i have also run the main query with a single join/subquery and the results are correct, both subqueries work with the main query and give the correctresults. it is only  when I add the 2nd join/subquery that the results are incorrect.

Comment: Thanx for the tip, I had to lookup what CTE is :) My background is MySQL but I now transitioning to T-SQL for work.

Comment: I think other rows are filtered out by your WHERE conditions because your are using left join, you need to specify how to handle null for columns other than a.POSCustomerStatus__c  and a.Mobile_1__c, e.g. b.IsActive__c IS NOT NULL AND b.b.IsActive__c  ='true'. You can also try to remove all the conditions except those from a and see the results